# Possible to output Docker syslog-ng container log to stdout & stderr while using Splunk logging driver?

Tags: docker, splunk

I have a container running Syslog-ng and I'm trying to feed syslog messages to Splunk.

Within the Syslog-ng container, there is a file /var/log/messages that stores any syslog messages that the container receives.  Is it possible for me to forward the container's /var/log/messages to stdout and stderr so that the syslog messages will be forwarded to my Splunk instance?

Here is an example of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  syslog-ng:
    image: balabit/syslog-ng:latest
    ports:
      - "514:514/udp"
      - "601:601"
    logging:
      driver: "splunk"
      options:
        splunk-token: "XXXX"
        splunk-url: "https://XXXX.splunkcloud.com"
        splunk-insecureskipverify: "true"
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.FullID}}"
        labels: type,location
        env: "os"
    labels:
      type: syslog
      location: home
    environment:
      - os=debian
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I can then exec into my container and run the command:

```
ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/messages
```

or

```
ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/messages
```

If I then send syslog messages to the container, I can view them in /var/log/messages.
They will not show up in stdout.

Running the following command will not show logs from /var/log/messages:

```
docker logs (containerid)
```

I can go to Splunk and see logs from when the container was created via stdout or stderr.  But Splunk will not show any further logs from the container receiving syslog messages.

Comment: you should be able to do this within the syslog-ng config file. there is the internal() source which is used to collect/handle syslog-ng messages. you might need to craft a custom config and mount it to the container to tweak this